# How to create a ROOT Histogram from a large file containing two columns of data? I only want to create a histogram from one column of data

Tags: c++, histogram, physics, root-framework

This is my code. Please let me know if there is a way to make the histogram without changing the code significantly. Additionally, let me know the easier way as well. Thank you.

```
{
TFile *f = new TFile("Data.root", "RECREATE");
TNtuple *t = new TNtuple("current_data", "Data from HV", "Unix:Current");
t->ReadFile("NP02_HVCurrent_10-09-2019_11-09-2019");
t->Write();

TH1F *h = new TH1F("Current_Hist", "Current Vs. Events", 100, -5, 5);
h->Fill("Current");
h->Draw();
}
```

Comment: FYI -- `TFile *f = new TFile("Data.root", "RECREATE"); TNtuple *t = new TNtuple("current_data", "Data from HV", "Unix:Current");` -- C++ is not Java.  There is no need to dynamically allocate there -- all you're doing is needlessly calling the allocator and creating memory leaks.  All you need is  `TFile f("Data.root", "RECREATE"); TNtuple t("current_data", "Data from HV", "Unix:Current");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not so far off. Like @PaulMcKenzie wrote there's no need to do dynamic allocations (though they are common in root usage code and prevent things from going out of scope while they are implicitly still needed ...)

The creation of the `TFile` and `t->Write()` seem superfluous for just creating and plotting the histogram.

For simply drawing a branch of a `TTree` (from which `TNtuple` inherits) there is often no need to do the boilerplate of creating the histogram. `TTree::Draw` is very versitile, there are various options:

```cpp
{
TNtuple t("current_data", "Data from HV", "Unix:Current");
t.ReadFile("NP02_HVCurrent_10-09-2019_11-09-2019");

// just draw
t.Draw("Current");

// draw with custom binning
t.Draw("Current>>(100,-5,5)");

// use a manually created histogram
TH1F h("Current_Hist", "Current Vs. Events", 100, -5, 5);
t.Draw("current>>Current_Hist");
}
```

Any of the `Draw` should also plot to the current canvas or create one if needed.

(For complex things that `TTree::Draw` cannot do, I'd recommend calling `MakeClass` on the `t`, which runs code generation. In the generated implementation file there should be a loop over all elements implemented already and you can add the histogram creation outside the loop and inside the loop `h.Fill(Current)`. NB: `Fill` does not take a string, it takes a float which needs to be the variable that holds the current tree element's value).

Comment: Thank you @pseyfert. Instead of TNtuple, if someone wants to use TTree then how does the given code change? Please show me how to create a branch and do the exact same thing.

Comment: nothing needs to be done to switch from TNtuple to TTree. TNtuple inherits from TTree, so every method of TTree is also a method of TNtuple.